# React 'Error: Maximum update depth exceeded.' with functional component and hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, components, react-hooks

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded.
```

With this component:

```
const UsersPage: React.FunctionComponent<UsersPageProps> = ({
  location,
  history,
  match,
}): JSX.Element => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { search } = location;

  const query = parseInt(location.search, 10);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState<number>(
    isNaN(query) || query < 0 ? 0 : query
  );

  const users = useSelector((state: any) => state.manageUsers.users.results);
  const isLoading = useSelector((state: any) => state.manageUsers.usersLoaded);
  const totalPages = useSelector(
    (state: any) => state.manageUsers.users.totalPages
  );
  const handlePaginationChange = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<any>,
    pageNumber: number
  ): void => {
    history.push(`${match.path}?page=${pageNumber ?? 0}`);
    setCurrentPage(pageNumber ?? 0);
  };

  const handleAddUserOnClick = () =>
    dispatch(manageUsersSetNewUserAndNavigate());
  const handleEditOnClick = (id) =>
    dispatch(manageUsersSetActiveEditUserAndNavigate(id));

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(manageUsersLoadUsers(currentPage));
  }, [currentPage]);

  return (
    <section className="users page">
      {!isLoading && <SectionLoaderWithMessage message={"Loading users..."} />}
      {isLoading && (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Toolbar disableGutters={true}>
            <Title flex={1}>Manage Users</Title>

            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="secondary"
              onClick={handleAddUserOnClick}
              startIcon={<AddCircle />}
            >
              Add User
            </Button>
          </Toolbar>
          <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table aria-label="table">
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
                  <TableCell style={{ fontWeight: "bold", minWidth: 150 }}>
                    Email
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell style={{ fontWeight: "bold", minWidth: 150 }}>
                    Name
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell style={{ fontWeight: "bold", minWidth: 150 }}>
                    Surname
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell style={{ fontWeight: "bold", minWidth: 150 }}>
                    Firm
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell style={{ fontWeight: "bold", minWidth: 150 }}>
                    Type
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell style={{ fontWeight: "bold", minWidth: 150 }}>
                    Enabled
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
              <TableBody>
                {users.map((user, index) => (
                  <TableRow
                    key={`${user.id}-${index}`}
                    onClick={() => handleEditOnClick(user.id)}
                    hover
                  >
                    <TableCell>{user.email}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{user.name}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{user.surname}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{user.firmName}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{user.type}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{`${user.enabled}`}</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                ))}
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
            <ThemedTablePagination
              totalPages={totalPages}
              pageNumber={currentPage}
              onChange={handlePaginationChange}
            />
          </TableContainer>
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </section>
  );
};

export default UsersPage;
```

I do not see anywhere in the render that is updating the state to cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Have you tried cutting this down to a [mre]?

Comment: I am not sure but I think the dispatch within useEffect re-render component. So when it rerender, useEffect is called  one more time until infinite.

Answer (score 1):

The function `handlePaginationChange` should be inside useEffect.

Currently each time `setCurrentPage` is called it re-render the component which in-turn calls the handlePaginationChange function again, hence calling setCurrentPage again and the cycle goes on and on.

Comment: Can you try placing a `console.count` in your current useEffect() ? And see if that is being called infinite times